# Why are rainy seasons different in different locations?

Tags: meteorology, climate

I noticed that the Middle East's rainy season generally runs from [November to May](https://weatherspark.com/y/104018/Average-Weather-in-Riyadh-Saudi-Arabia-Year-Round#Sections-Rain); but Florida, which is at almost the same latitude, is exactly the opposite, peaking from [May to November](https://weatherspark.com/y/18622/Average-Weather-in-Miami-Florida-United-States-Year-Round#Sections-Rain).  Can anyone provide a rationale as to why?

Thanks.

Comment: One is mid lattiude weather(Middle East) depends on frontal dynamics and the other is tropical weather depends on movement of ITCZ.

Comment: Even Your statement that Florida sees maximum precipitation from May to November is only for non El Nino years.

Comment: Thanks!  The ITCZ is therefore "inverting" what would ordinarily be the the same schedule then, since they're close in latitude?  That's wild...

Comment: I stand corrected about the ITCZ. Maybe South Florida remains tropical and is influenced by ITCZ movement but North Florida is not influenced by it.

Comment: JordanFine the middle east is part of the horse latitudes so that is where monsoon wilds subside

Comment: @gansub I would venture that his statement for about Florida is entirely true, regardless of ENSO phase

Comment: Looks like for Orlando only one out of 120 years has had more rainfall Nov-April than from May-Nov! (That year 2010 did have an intense wet winter during El Niño, then a drier summer during La Niña) And only 11 of the cool season years are even within 10 inches. I know nothing about Middle East rain precip off hand, and would have to dig more for data than the easy sources I'm familiar with for the US, so can't speak on that side.

Comment: (And I also don't know if it's different in FL east coast spots where onshore flow is more important in winter, and seabreeze precip is easier to miss in the summer... it may well be... but indeed Jordan hit the mark on Orlando at least!)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest You are the expert for that part of the world but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Florida  "During El Niño, Florida sees greater rainfall between November and March"

Comment: @gansub definitely true in general, but the scale is reasonably small in comparison to the big picture there :-)

Comment: So then what's the true reason Florida and the ME are ordinarily completely inverted timeframe-wise?  The rains of the ME roughly correlate to late fall/winter, whereas the rains of FL correlate to spring/summer?